# Yii sometimes pass data to view error due high traffic

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I have problem with passing data to view on Yii when traffic is quite high (>400 user). first I get data from cookies and pass to view, but it show different value on the page, but when I checked cookies on inspect element it still has the first value.

here's some pieces of the code:

```
$cookies_username = Yii::app()->request->cookies['USERNAME'];
$cookies_group = Yii::app()->request->cookies['GROUP'];
$data = array();
$data['username'] = $cookies_username;
$data['group'] = $cookies_group;
$this->render('index', $data);
```

I use this for chat data, when user refresh page, sometimes they get the wrong username. Anyone know what happen with this kind of error and how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: which version of Yii you are using?

Comment: try to put your code on a isolated function, with receives Yii::app()->request as a paremeter, and returns $data.